# Change "Me" on Google Photo

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, google-photos

When I search "Me" in Google Photo, it shows pictures of a friend, not my pictures. My face group there is labeled "Gideon" and my friend's is "James". When you visit my friend James pictures (Albums > People and Pet > James), you will see that the name label is "James (Me)". How can a move that grey "(Me)" identifier from my friend face group to my picture group labeled "Gideon"?

Comment: Please read the tag(s) you included. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions here? https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7378566

Comment: @DavidPostill I apologise. am aware that only the [google-photos] tag is applicable here. But StackExchane wont let me ask the question without giving exactly 3 tags. If you could help me and provide the other two related tags (I'm sorry, I don't know which other tags will be suitable), I'll edit the question.

Comment: @RayB There is no "Face labeled as me" > "Remove" > "Remove label" is missing from the settings menu.